# Getting the zoom level (pinch) on Android 2.2 mobile browser webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an info box that I would like to popup on a mobile website, the info box has a responsive design and sets the width to the full width of the page and also takes into consideration the zoom level.

How I do this in IOS and Newer Androids: I get the `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` and compare them with screen height and width. However, in Android 2.2 `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` do not report the right values. Can anyone think of a way around this?

Comment: I'm currently looking into this as well.  Apparently this is due to the way Android 2 reports `innerHeight`, and is documented here: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html#t01  If I find a solution, I'll be sure to let you know!